Static Resources are not being served in Spring Boot
I'm porting a Spring app to Spring Boot v3.3.4, but my static resources aren't being served up by Spring Boot.  I have my static assets (html, css, js, png, etc) under src\main\resources\static.  Here are the exert from my logs when I try to load url /index.html.

[DEBUG] 2024-11-02 14:16:57.789 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1]  c.f.a.u.CustomRequestLoggingFilter - Before request [GET /index.html, headers=[host:"localhost:8443", connection:"keep-alive", pragma:"no-cache", cache-control:"no-cache", sec-ch-ua:""Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"", sec-ch-ua-mobile:"?0", sec-ch-ua-platform:""Windows"", upgrade-insecure-requests:"1", user-agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", sec-fetch-site:"none", sec-fetch-mode:"navigate", sec-fetch-user:"?1", sec-fetch-dest:"document", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br, zstd", accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.9", cookie:"Idea-2ba4f510=04bef4d7-875e-4491-bdd6-da8a4b98ccba; JSESSIONID=465E301E3CAD061A3DA5584DE01C1C59"]]
[WARN ] 2024-11-02 14:16:57.791 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1]  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /index.html
[WARN ] 2024-11-02 14:16:57.791 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1]  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No endpoint GET /index.html.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-02 14:16:57.792 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1]  c.f.a.u.CustomRequestLoggingFilter - After request [GET /index.html, headers=[host:"localhost:8443", connection:"keep-alive", pragma:"no-cache", cache-control:"no-cache", sec-ch-ua:""Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"", sec-ch-ua-mobile:"?0", sec-ch-ua-platform:""Windows"", upgrade-insecure-requests:"1", user-agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", sec-fetch-site:"none", sec-fetch-mode:"navigate", sec-fetch-user:"?1", sec-fetch-dest:"document", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br, zstd", accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.9", cookie:"Idea-2ba4f510=04bef4d7-875e-4491-bdd6-da8a4b98ccba; JSESSIONID=465E301E3CAD061A3DA5584DE01C1C59"]]

As I understand things resources/static should be automatically served without additional configuration.  But, something in my port may have turned it off?  I don't have much loaded in my configs.
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.groovy().cache(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add( new JsonConverter() );
        converters.add( new FileMessageConverter() );
        converters.add( new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SpringBootUrlRewriteFilter> urlRewriteFilter(@Value(SpringBootUrlRewriteFilter.CONFIG_LOCATION) Resource config) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<SpringBootUrlRewriteFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(new SpringBootUrlRewriteFilter(config));
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setName("urlRewriteFilter");
        registration.setOrder(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER-5);
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD,DispatcherType.REQUEST);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public AngularViewTemplateProcessor createAngularViewTemplateProcessor() {
        return new AngularViewTemplateProcessor();
    }
}

And AppConfig
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.fuseanalytics")
@PropertySources(value = {
        @PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"}),
        @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:server.${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties"}),
        @PropertySource(value={"file:${server.data.home}/credentials/credentials.properties"}),
        @PropertySource(value={"classpath:wro.${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties"})
})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBcryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

How should I go about debugging this?  I've been tracing through Spring code trying to figure out what is causing it to miss serving the assets, but no luck.  So I have to think there is an easier way to troubleshoot this.  Any ideas?

The problem I was having is the use of @EnableWebMvc.  By using this annotation I was turning off the WebMvcAutoConfiguration facility which would've added support to load static resources through the resources/static directory.  Removing that annotation re-enable auto configuration and allowed me to see the assets.
